# Java method for wait, then re-execute?

Tags: java

So atm my code looks like this:

```
FetchUpdates() {
if (checkupdatesComplete) {
  FetchUpdatedsneeded();
  }else{
  //wait until checkupdates == true, then re execute FetchUpdates();
  }
```

Pretty much i'm stuck on the else statement... Anyone know the method for what i put in "//"?

This is the only way i know how to call the FetchUpdates method after checking for needed updates.

```
 static File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Directory"); 
 static File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\File"); 

public void checkforUpdates() {
if (f1.exists) { 
checkVersion();
}else{ 
F1Exists =false;
} 
FetchUpdates(); 
} 

Public void FetchUpdates() { 
if (!F1Exists) { 
try (InputStream in = URI.create("C:\\DownloadUrlHere").toURL().openStream()) {
                    Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:\\DirectoryHere"));
                }catch(Exception ex){}
 }
```

Comment: this isn't a do-your-homework site

Comment: You should be giving some more detail....

Comment: It's unclear what your environment is (ATM = "Abstinence 'Till Marriage"?  "Adobe Type Manager"?  "Air Turbine Motor"?), but in the majority of environments (graphic apps, servers, et al) one should never "wait" inside a program.

Comment: This isn't homework lol. It's just a thing i've been stuck on for about 2 hours now.
& @ Hot Licks I'm making a desktop program (Launcher for my game). My previous update system was complete crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(!checkupdates){
        FetchUpdatedsneeded();
       if (checkupdates) {
          execute FetchUpdates();        
          break;
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for updates when `checkupdates` is set to `true`, just fetch updates when `FetchUpdates` is called.

Comment: put it backwards apostrophes, the key is under the escape key.